# Web has multiple contacts for a business or bank; which is real?

Tags: scams, websites

"A websearch finds five or six different phone numbers for my bank. Are they all real, or is one or more of them a scam? How do I know for sure?"

Comment: That's nothing. Try searching for Microsoft tech support.

Comment: FWIW, the official word from Microsoft is that _there is no phone number for tech support._ All contact must initially be through their website's chat function. If you can't use chat because Windows is completely booked, borrow someone else's machine to get to the chat. If you can't do that, get a friend to use the chat to ask them to call you in the next day or two; supposedly they will do so, though "I hae me doots." Don't complain here; complain to MS... or get off Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is a new trend, with scammers abusing search engine optimization to try to get people looking for a bank to come to their fake sites instead.

Always contact your bank directly. Check where the search engine is pointing you and make sure it's really your bank's page. Ideally, don't rely on search at all; get the address or phone number from the back of your credit card or a paper document the bank has mailed you; you can bookmark that in the browser or add it to your phone's contact list for easy reference. (I also have these stored in my password manager.)

You may want to take similar precautions for other business.

And as always, be suspicious of any link you are e-mailed or phone number you are given that you didn't explicitly request, whether it's from bank, business, or government; make sure it goes where it claims to go, and if there is any doubt whatsoever use your stored information instead.

As a programmer might say, practice safe hex.

Comment: If you know your bank's *real* website (you should), you can go there and find the phone number.